# How is 'this.randomGenes' not a function?

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

so I'm having a bit o trouble with this p5js script. I'm getting a TypeError saying "this.randomGenes is not a function" but it looks like one to me... I don't understand where the error's coming from. it's all spelled right, all the semi-colons are there, all the brackets are closed, all the parentheses are too. The error just won't stand out to me.

```
function DNA(genes) {
    this.maxWeight = 25;
    this.maxSpeed = 25;

    if (genes) {
        this.genes = genes;
    } else {
        this.genes = []; // weight, position, maxspeed, rgba
        this.randomGenes();
    }

    this.randomGenes = function() {
        this.genes[0] = random(this.maxWeight);
        this.genes[1] = [random(height), random(width)];
        this.genes[2] = random(this.maxSpeed);
        this.genes[3] = [random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the code sequentially :) At the point, where you're calling it, it's not yet defined.

Comment: `this` is by default scoped to `function`

Comment: where are you calling the method?

Comment: @qqilihq That's perfectly OK. The issue is about the incorrect binding of `this`.

Comment: Ousmane Diaw - the method (if i'm understanding right) is being called in each separate individual. excatly like this: "indiv = new DNA();"    qqilihq - I feel like I'm not doing anything different than i have in the past so I'm not sure how it's not defined yet.    Maciej Kozieja - scope is still kind of a mystery to me so I'm not sure how to change that

Comment: @ScottMarcus Calling `DNA()` will cause a `TypeError: this.randomGenes is not a function`, triggered by `this.randomGenes();` in the `else` branch which is invoked **before** `this.randomGenes` is ever defined.

Comment: @qqilihq ohhh okay I see it now. I had to look at some of my old code to understand what you meant

Comment: @qqilihq See my updated answer showing that the function should be attached to the prototype. This corrects that issue.

Comment: @theDr34mer See my updated answer (and specifically the second code snippet) for the correct way to structure your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an "instance" of your DNA function in order for `this` to bind to that object instance and then you can call `randomGenes` from that instance. If you just run the `DNA` function, `this` will be bound incorrectly and the function won't be found.

```js
function DNA(genes) {
    this.maxWeight = 25;
    this.maxSpeed = 25;

    if (genes) {
        this.genes = genes;
    } else {
        this.genes = []; // weight, position, maxspeed, rgba
        this.randomGenes();
    }

    this.randomGenes = function() {
        this.genes[0] = random(this.maxWeight);
        this.genes[1] = [random(height), random(width)];
        this.genes[2] = random(this.maxSpeed);
        this.genes[3] = [random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255)];
    }
}

// Make an instance of the DNA object so that `this` gets bound to it
var DNA1 = new DNA("myGenes");

// Now, you can call the function via the instance
// Here, this will cause an error about "random" not being defined, but
// that actually proves that "randomGenes" was invoked.
DNA1.randomGenes();
```

Now, as @qqilihq mentioned in the comments, if your instance is created without any argument being passed, you will get your error because you are attempting to call the function before it's been assigned as a method. To correct this, we need to alter the code, but that same alteration should also happen for another reason...

When you make a new instance of a function, the function is known as a "function constructor" because you call it to construct object instances. Since (usually) all instances of an object use the same behaviors (methods), we typically add those methods to the object's underlying "prototype" object that all instances will inherit from. This way you only have to store the function once and all instances will inherit it. By moving your function into the prototype, it is in memory before any instances actually get made and therefore solves, not only your problem, but also is more efficient.

So, your code really should be:

```js
    function DNA(genes) {
        // Instance properties get created using the "this" keyword
        // inside the constructor function
        this.maxWeight = 25;
        this.maxSpeed = 25;

        if (genes) {
            this.genes = genes;
        } else {
            this.genes = []; // weight, position, maxspeed, rgba
            this.randomGenes();
        }
    }
    
    // By adding the function to the prototype of DNA, all instances constructed
    // via the DNA constructor function will inherit the method:
    DNA.prototype.randomGenes = function() {
            this.genes[0] = random(this.maxWeight);
            this.genes[1] = [random(height), random(width)];
            this.genes[2] = random(this.maxSpeed);
            this.genes[3] = [random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255)];
    }

    // Make an instance of the DNA object so that `this` gets bound to it
    var DNA1 = new DNA();

    // Now, you can call the function via the instance
    // Here, this will cause an error about "random" not being defined, but
    // that actually proves that "randomGenes" was invoked.
    DNA1.randomGenes();
```

Comment: I still haven't used prototypes X.D which, I've seen them many times so I should understand how important they are. I'll have to learn more about them

Comment: update: I did the prototype version you mentioned and everything works now. thank you for the help!

Comment: @theDr34mer You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote the answer and mark as "the" answer.